Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while uploading file to firebase storage from flutter in IOS only
i'm facing some problems while uploading file to firebase storage the issue is in IOS only and working fine in android.
plugin used:
firebase_storage: 11.0.7  firebase_auth: 4.2.0  firebase_core: 2.9.0
Future uploadImageToStorage() async {
  CommonService.instance.isLoding.value = true;
  final image = File(fileData.value!.path);
  String filename = fileData.value!.path
    .substring(fileData.value!.path.lastIndexOf('/'))
    .toString();
  final metadata = SettableMetadata(
   contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  );
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  Reference ref = storage.ref().child("users/${CommonService.instance.loggedInUserID.value}/uploads$filename");
  UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
  uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
   switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
    case TaskState.running:
     final progress =
       100.0 * (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes);
     print("Upload is $progress% complete.");
     break;
    case TaskState.paused:
     print("Upload is paused.");
     break;
    case TaskState.canceled:
     print("Upload was canceled");
     break;
    case TaskState.error:
     break;
    case TaskState.success:
     break;
   }
  });
 } 

so when i try calling this function when it comes at UploadTask, my application in IOS is getting breaked and it shows this error Error : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.
I have tried many solutions try all the tutorials/documentations from internet.
